# How to bridge 2 wireless cards on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, ip

I have 2 wireless cards on a Windows 7 machine. One (nano USB Realtex NIC) is on the 192.168.1.x subnet and is connected to a wireless router (192.168.1.1) from which it is assigned an IP address via DHCP. The router acts as the gateway to the internet.

The other card (internal WiFi NIC) is connected to an ad-hoc (IBSS) wireless network on the 10.0.0.x subnet and has a static IP of 10.0.0.40.

This setup works well - both network adapters are enabled and working - I am able to connect to the internet, as well as SSH to other devices on the ad-hoc network.

What I would like to do is to bridge the 2 networks so that devices on the ad-hoc network can connect to the internet via the adapter on the 192.168.1.x subnet.

I have tried to find an answer but it proves to be hard; my current configuration on the laptop is:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 19...80 3f 5d 18 df c7 ......Realtek RTL8188EU Wireless LAN 802.11n USB 2.0 Network Adapter
 13...88 25 2c c3 b4 39 ......Realtek RTL8188CE Wireless LAN 802.11n COMBO PCI-E NIC
 12...5c 26 0a 24 6e 2b ......Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 21...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 22...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
 23...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.109     25
         10.0.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link         10.0.0.40    281
        10.0.0.40  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.0.40    281
       10.0.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.0.40    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.109    281
    192.168.1.109  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.109    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.109    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         10.0.0.40    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.109    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.0.40    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.109    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 13    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 19    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 13    281 fe80::1866:53b8:6467:ff1c/128
                                    On-link
 19    281 fe80::f546:abf0:1f4:cb52/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 13    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
 19    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

On the adhoc network I have a Raspberry Pi with static IP of 10.0.0.3, with the following config in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface etho0 inet dhcp
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 10.0.0.3
netmask 255.255.255.0
#gateway 10.0.0.0
wireless-channel 1
wireless-essid Team2
wireless-mode ad-hoc
```

What I would like to be able to do is to successfully ping www.google.com from the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: You can't do it with bridging. If you could, we wouldn't need WDS, we'd just bridge. That would be swell, but that's not reality.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is configure *Internet sharing*. I've tried it several times, and repeatedly failed until I found the *right* tutorial.

Here's how you do it:

- On the Windows computer, the one that will share the connection:

  - Open the Network & Sharing Center
  - On the left side of the screen, click on "Modify card parameters" (or something like that, my Windows is in French...)
  - Right-click the card *that provides the Internet connection* (in your case, the Realtex USB). If you don't know, you can check the IP in Status -> Details
  - Click "Properties" then go to tab "Sharing"
  - Check the topmost box
  - In the dropdown menu, select the card *that will receive the connection* (in your case, the internal one)
  - Click OK
  - **Don't** reboot
- On the computers that will receive the connection:

  - If they are configured to use DHCP, don't do anything.
  - If they are not, set their default gateway the the IP of the Windows computer (in your case `10.0.0.40`)

Doing this works when I need to provide Internet to Hyper-V VMs on my own computer (Windows 10 Pro), it should work as well for you. The only problem is, you may have to undo/redo the manipulation on the Windows computer everytime it reboots (my VMs don't have Internet until I do).

Comment: Thanks very much for your help - I've tried your suggestion but weirdly, I get no 'Sharing' tab on my adapter properties. I have tried what is suggested online - that is to start the Internet Connection Service via services.msc but when I do this I get 'Error message: The internet connection sharing service on local computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs' . Followed some suggestions to try and resolve that issue but no luck so far!

Comment: I'm guessing that you have your two cards bridged still, I don't believe you can bridge and share so you will need to unbridge the 2 cards to allow internet sharing.